# FIXED: How to get response from Firebase Cloud Function to confirm email submission in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-functions, httprequest, nodemailer, bootstrap-vue

I've been struggling to find out how I can get a response in the client side after making the HTTP POST request in Firebase Cloud Functions, to show a Bootstrap Vue Toast, to let the user know that the email was sent.
I am getting the email on my gmail like it should, but from the client side, you can't figure out if you have successfully sent it or not, since the Toast isn't showing.

Does anyone has an idea? 
Thank you in advance!

Code from Vue:

```
Vue.axios
        .post(
          "https://us-central1-xxxxxxxxxx-website-d4f43.cloudfunctions.net/xxxxxxx",
          {
            email: this.form.email,
            subject: this.form.subject,
            message: this.form.message,
          }
        ).then((res) => {
          this.makeToast(res.msg, {
            autoHideDelay: 1000,
            title: "Email confirmation",
            variant: "success",
            solid: true,
          });
          this.form.email = "";
          this.form.subject = null;
          this.form.message = "";
        });
```

Code from Cloud Function:

```
exports.emailMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    const data = req.body;
    const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request!</p>
    <h3>Contact details</h3>
    <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${data.message}</p>
    `;
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: gmailEmail,
        pass: gmailPassword,
      },
    });
    const mailOptions = {
      from: '"S2P Website" <xxxxxx@gmail.com>',
      to: "yyyyyyy@gmail.com",
      subject: `${data.subject}`,
      html: output
    };
    let stuff = transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (res, error) => {
      if (error) {
       return console.log(error);
     }
     return res.send({
       msg: "Your email has been sent!",
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: *"but from the client side, you can't figure out if you have successfully sent it or not."* - what's the problem?  Your function is sending a response.  You should be able to get that out of `res`.  What is the specific problem here?  What are you observing, and what have you tried in order to debug this?

Comment: @DougStevenson The function sends the email to my account saying that someone has filled the form, but the Toast is never deployed with the info "You email has been sent!", after submitting the contact request. I should have access to the res but I simply don't and I can't figure why. I've tried to use console.logs but they never show up on the console and I have no idea why...

Comment: My problem doesn't have any issue, like Doug stated. Firebase can take some time to update and that was the issue. In my case it took about 24 hours to update, hence my dilemma on why it wasn't working when it should!